# Unable to mount image file

Tags: mount, partition, disk-image

I am trying to mount `image_file_name.img` which has multiple partitions to a directory, but without success.

Partition details:

```
sfdisk -l -uS image_file_name.img 
Disk image_file_name.img: cannot get geometry

Disk image_file_name.img: 11 cylinders, 255 heads, 63 sectors/track
Warning: The partition table looks like it was made
  for C/H/S=*/4/63 (instead of 11/255/63).
For this listing I'll assume that geometry.
Units = sectors of 512 bytes, counting from 0

   Device Boot    Start       End   #sectors  Id  System
image_file_name.img1           252       503        252  83  Linux
image_file_name.img2           504    177407     176904  83  Linux
image_file_name.img3             0         -          0   0  Empty
image_file_name.img4             0         -          0   0  Empty
```

I am running the following `mount` command:

```
mount -o offset=$((252*512)) image_file_name.img /tmp/abc/
```

Error message:

```
mount: mounting /dev/loop0 on /tmp/abc/ failed: Invalid argument
```

The corresponding error in `dmesg` is

```
[106359.764567] NTFS-fs error (device loop0): parse_options(): Unrecognized mount option offset.
```

This is on a limited operating system without tools such as `kpartx`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the error you’re seeing in `dmesg`, I would skip `offset` as a `mount` option and rely on `losetup` instead.

With `util-linux`’s `losetup`, you can use partition handling:

```
losetup -P -f --show image_file_name.img
```

This will show the name of the loop device used; use that to mount, using

```
mount /dev/loop0p1 /tmp/abc
```

but replacing `loop0` (*not* `p1`) as appropriate. The other partitions will be accessible using `p2` etc.

With `busybox`’s `losetup`, you’ll need to specify the offset directly:

```
losetup -o $((252*512)) -f image_file_name.img
```

then mount the loop device directly, *e.g.*

```
mount /dev/loop0 /tmp/abc
```

If you unmount the file system, you should also free up the loop device with `losetup -d`.